# facebook embedded rendering over my static menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I have a website with a static menu that stays at the top of the screen. I achieved this with the following CSS code:

```
#menu
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I have a div with the id 'menu' that displays correctly. All the other material in the webpage renders below or under the menu like it is suppose to. I then went to facebook and got the code so I could include the facebook feed of a page. Facebook gave me 2 sets of code, javascript and some html. I inserted those and now when it is rendered, the facebook newsfeed renders above my static menu.

Here is the code that facebook gave me:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/magnoliahealthyliving/" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/magnoliahealthyliving/"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/magnoliahealthyliving/">Magnolia Healthy Living</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

I need my menu to render ontop of the facebook embedded html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 
`z-index: 1'  or 999 to #menu.

```
#menu { 
     position: fixed;
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     width: 100%; 
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0; 
     z-index: 1; /*NEW*/
 }
```